# Chrome 42 on Ubuntu 14.04 won't start

Tags: google-chrome

Running Chrome 42 on Ubuntu 14.04 results in an error going out to console of:

```
Check failed: NamespaceUtils::WriteToIdMapFile("/proc/self/gid_map", gid_)
```

I found this in the Chromium project which might point to the issue: [Writing gid_map file is sometimes restricted in the Linux kernel](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457362). However, I have no idea how to disable setgroups. It's a single user system, so I'm not worried about other accounts. Kernel version is 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP.

Comment: Issue has been reported here, you can join the thread:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480017

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you can still use Chromium with parameters:
chromium --disable-namespace-sandbox

Comment: Please provide some additional background information.